# Screen touch locations on IPad3

Tags: ipad, touch

I'm writing an OpenGL game for iPhone & iPad, controlled by screen touches.  It's a universal app, so I have code in touchesBegan to convert any touch location into the range 0.0-1.0 (one side of the screen to the other, which is how the rest of the app needs to get the touch info).  The code that does this is:

```
CGPoint touchLocationPx;
GLFloat xx;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchLocationPx = [touch locationInView:self];    // touchLocationPx.x & .y are in points, not pixels...
    xx = (GLfloat)touchLocationPx.x / (GLfloat)(self.frame.size.width);    // self.frame.size.width is also in points,
                                                                           // so xx is in the range 0.0 to 1.0...

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Set xx to a dummy value that will not be processed by the rest of the app...
    xx = -999.999;
}
```

It relies on [touch locationInView:self] and self.frame.size.width always being in the same units (points rather than pixels as I understand it) regardless of whether it's a non-retina screen, a retina screen with [UIIScreen mainScreen].scale=2.0, or an iPad in x1 or x2 mode.  (My own test device is an iPhone 4S and if I monitor screen size and touch locations it all gets reported in points (480,320) as expected. 
However I've since heard that on iPad3 the controls were unresponsive.  Are screen size and touch location handled differently on this device? Or could something else be causing my code to not convert the touch location correctly?
(On the simulator all device types work fine including retina iPad. I know the simulator will never exactly match a real device, but something as fundamental as how touch locations are reported should be in there properly.  Any idea why the real device fails?)

Thanks,

Sam.